# How can I combine two PDF pages show up on the same page?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am looking for a free tool that allows re-arranging pages of a PDF document and combining multiple pages per sheet. The first part (re-arranging) is easily solved by many tools (I use [PyPDF](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/)).

The problem is with the second requirement: to combine two (or more) pages into single page. For example, take two pages (A and B), rotate them, scale and combine into a single page like this

```
------       ------            ------
|     |      |      |          |     |
|  A  |      |  B   |          | a   |
|     |      |      |          |     |
|     |      |      |  --->    ------
|     |      |      |          |     |        
|     |      |      |          | b   |        
|     |      |      |          |     |        
------       ------            ------
```

The solution needs to work on Linux and preferably on Windows too. I'm looking for either console application or library with Python or Perl bindings.

**Edit** there is [pdfnup](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfnup/0.3.3) library that is supposed to perform exactly this kind of transformation, and is cross-platform, however I cannot use it due to a bug similar to [this](http://two.pairlist.net/pipermail/reportlab-users/2008-December/007819.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465271/gluing-imposition-pdf-documents/466110#466110) that uses [Multivalent](http://multivalent.sourceforge.net/index.html) to impose PDF pages

Answer (score 26):

This is a summary of the tools I found for PDF (I wanted to find the equivalent of psup and psbook)

- Create booklets: pdfbook, pdf-tools (command: pdfbklt)
- Merge PDF files: pdfmerge, pdfjam (command: pdfjoin)
- Rotate pages: pdfjam (command: pdf90)
- Multiple pages per sheet: pdfjam (command: pdfnup)
- Create posters (multiple sheets per page): pdfposter

From my package manager:

- pdf-tools: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-PDF
- pdfbook: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/pdfbook/
- pdfmerge: https://github.com/dmaphy/pdfmerge
- pdfjam: http://go.warwick.ac.uk/pdfjam
- pdfposter: http://pdfposter.origo.ethz.ch/

Create an A6 booklet:

```
pdfbook -2 -p a5 infile.pdf outfile.pdf
```

pdf-tools contains:

- pdfbklt: create booklets
- pdfrevert: Removes one layer of changes to a PDF file, trying to maximise the size of the output file (to account for linearised PDF).
- pdfstamp: Adds the given string to the infile .pdf file at the given location, font and size.

There is also multivalent: http://multivalent.sourceforge.net/Tools/index.html

Comment: New home for pdfmerge (it seems): https://github.com/dmaphy/pdfmerge

Comment: After testing several tools, `pdfjam` was for me definitively the simplest, fastest & most efficient : `pdfjam *.pdf --nup 2x1 --landscape --outfile output.pdf` ( from: http://superuser.com/a/750293/255048 )

Answer (score 9):

On Linux, you can convert the PDF files to Postscript and use `psnup`. The exact way to invoke it depends on exactly how you want the pages to be put together, whether you want them rotated, what paper size(s) you want to use, etc. but it'll be something like this:

```
pdf2ps infile.pdf infile.ps
psnup -2 infile.ps outfile.ps
ps2pdf outfile.ps outfile.pdf
```

Depending on what tools you have available, you might have a more efficient way to do this - `psnup` is certainly not the only way, but it's a relatively well-known program (on Linux anyway).

Comment: Should that be `pdf2ps infile.pdf infile.ps`?

Comment: @Ian: I do believe you're right, thanks for catching that ;) I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Linux, you can use [BookletImposer](http://kjo.herbesfolles.org/bookletimposer/) for putting multiple PDF pages on one single page.

For Ubuntu users, this tool is available at Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question, you'll need a PDF 'Imposition' tool, which is a fancy way of saying a tool that arranges PDF page images onto a particular array to create a NEW single PDF page.  Imagine it's something like typesetting a newspaper.  You define an array of slots a certain number of columns wide, by a certain number of rows deep, on a page of a certain fixed dimensions (in cm).  Then you fill those empty slots top to bottom, left to right with pages from a pdf source-file.  In the case of the OP, they want to create a single page, composed of two 8.5x11 pages arranged in a 1x2 array (1 column, 2 rows).  Their pages will be dropped into the array in the following order: 1,2.  So you are dropping the first page (page 1 of the pdf) into the first slot of your array (Column 1, row 1), and you are dropping the second page (page 2) into the second slot (Column 1, row 2).

How to use the tool to make this happen:
Download the old version of Multivalent.  Note the author removed the good tool classes from the latest edition without explanation, so you have to use an older one. Here's a working link as of 02/12:
http://code.google.com/p/pdfsizeopt/downloads/detail?name=Multivalent20060102.jar
For simplicity, I renamed the jar file to m.jar.
It sort of goes without saying that you need to install JRE for this to work, but I'll put it out there.
Add m.jar to your Java Class Path Environment variables (for scripting) or run the command line syntax with the -cp option and the relative path (shown below).  Note, I ran it FROM the command-line at the install directory in my example below.  Provide an absolute path from root otherwise (like c:\1\bin\m.jar).

Here is an example that will accomplish exactly what OP posted about:
C:\1\bin>java -cp m.jar tool.pdf.Impose -dim 1x2 -verbose -papersize "21.59x55.88cm" -layout "1,2" yourfilename.pdf

Note, the -dim option creates the array in Columns x Rows.  The -papersize is specified in centimeters here, but if you need inches, just multiply inches by 2.54 to get cm.  The -layout option gives you the order you want to fill the empty slots in your array, filling from top to bottom and left to right.  In this case, we want page one of the pdf on top and page two on the bottom, so our argument is "1,2".  The final argument is your actual source file.  The tool will output a file called yourfilename-up.pdf when you are done.

Hope that helps.

-Matt Zweil

Answer (score 0):

Check the source code of PyPDF, especially the rotateClockwise() method. There must be a place where the content of a page is written. Insert a "q" operator (save state) and "cm" (with the correct parameters for a scaling matrix) before the content and a "Q" operator (restore state) afterwards.

See the [PDF documentation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/) for an explanation of operators and the structure of a page (scroll to the bottom for some useful links).

Don't forget to send a patch to PyPDF :)

[EDIT] You might also want to check the [pdfjam sources](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic/firth/software/pdfjam) which include a pdfnup command.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perl function I use to grab a directory full of prn files from a 3rd party app and create a single merged pdf.

```
sub runMerged($)
{
    my($path) = @_;

    print "Generating merged PDFs for $path\n";

    my @files = sort(getFiles($path, ".prn\$"));
    if (scalar(@files))
    {
        open(MERGE, ">$path/merged.prn");
        for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@files); $i++)
        {
            print MERGE "^L\n" if ($i > 0);

            open(FN, "$path/" . $files[$i]);
            while (my $line = <FN>)
            {
                print MERGE $line;
            }
            close(FN);
        }

        chdir("$BASE_PATH/txt2pdf");
        print `./txt2pdf.pl $path/merged.prn`;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Had a similar need this week.
But I needed to repeat each A4 page (landscape) "twice" in the A3 sheet (portrait), to later cut then in half.

I found a Acrobat Plugin with tons of imposition features that worked great for my needs, and with a fully functional 30 days trial.

Hope It could be helpfull for someone else.
http://www.pdfsnake.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you and this is what I did:

1. Extracted all the pages in the pdf file as a separate file each
2. In irfanView (with plugins) I created a Vertical "Panoramic" image
3. Dragged the pdf files over to the images section
4. Clicked created
5. The "image" is created with all the pages following each other as one very long vertical image
6. You can export to PDF with almost no loss in quality.
7. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script for repeating pages (like A5, landscape) twice on a sheet double this size (A4, portrait):

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUTFILE=$*
PAGENUM=`pdftk ${INPUTFILE} dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | cut -d : -f 2  | cut -d " " -f 2`
PAGES=`seq 1 ${PAGENUM}`
DUPAGES=`for i in ${PAGES} ; do echo $i $i | tr "\n" " " ; done`
OUTPUT1=`basename ${INPUTFILE} .pdf`.dup.pdf
OUTPUT2=`basename ${INPUTFILE} .pdf`.double.pdf
pdftk ${INPUTFILE} cat ${DUPAGES} output ${OUTPUT1}
pdfjam --nup 1x2 ${OUTPUT1} --outfile ${OUTPUT2}
```

It's not really elegant; it could be done without the second pdftk call, and it does not work with files containing spaces. But it works with multi-page pdfs.

Answer (score 0):

Using Adobe Acrobat XI Pro, open the 1st document.
Edit, select "take a snapshot", then click at the top corner of what you want to copy and drag to the opposite corner.
Have an open clean sheet in Paint.
Click over to the clean sheet in paint and control V to paste the 1st document into the clean sheet.
Repeat for the 2nd item that you want to combine on the same page except position the 2nd item UNDER the 1st item temporarily in your Paint sheet.
Then drag the 2nd item to position it where you need it in the Paint Sheet.
Save the paint sheet file and you are done!

Comment: Adobe Acrobat XI Pro is not a free tool, is it? That is what the OP asked for.

Comment: We don't usually put humans in our programs here.  (not that the question is on-topic, anyway)