# PyPDF2 mergeTranslatedPage doesn't work on some pdf's

Tags: pdf, pypdf

With some input files my merging 2 pages into 1 page side-by-side fails. I can't find out why! 
Sample test code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import sys
print ("2-up input " + sys.argv[1])
input1 = PdfFileReader(open(sys.argv[1], "rb"), strict=False)
output = PdfFileWriter()

lhs = input1.getPage(0)
rhs = input1.getPage(1)
lhs.mergeTranslatedPage(rhs, 420,0, True)
output.addPage(lhs)
outputStream = open(sys.argv[2], "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

The failed cases generate an output file which has ONLY the lhs page, whereas a good output has lhs and rhs pages next to each other.

A possible clue: when I run the script on a "bad" input file I get this message:
"PdfReadWarning: Xref table not zero-indexed. ID numbers for objects will be corrected. [pdf.py:1503]"

Comment: Please provide the files in question. If the issue only occurs for *some input files*, there seems to be something special about them.

Comment: If you're not wedded to PyPDF2, another Python library that can merge PDFs is [pdfrw](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/).  It has 4-up and 2up examples.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is a problem with pyPDF2. I tried an alternative non-Python solution, based on [Gluing (Imposition) ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465271/gluing-imposition-pdf-documents) (see the 4th answer by Wang).

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# converts pdf file to 2-up pdf file
# command line argument is pdf file name
# output is output.pdf
pdftops $1 - | psnup -Pa5 -m0.6in -2 -q | pstopdf -i -o output.pdf
```

This **does** work on the troublesome files that PyPDF2 choked on.
Note that the formatting arguments to pnup will depend on your documents.

I'm still learning how they work!

Comment: If your *bad files* actually are broken, it's not a *problem with pyPDF2* but aproblem with the files.

Comment: I confirm the same. 'mergeTranslatedPage' worked on some pdf files and did not work on others. It's even worked on some pages of a pdf and not on others. Those pages that worked on have no fonts (only an image that has been added as a new page to that pdf file with acrobat pdf pro).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I did not check, but, here:

```
output.addPage(lhs)
```

You ask python to add to the new file only 1 page, and this page is lhs.
Try to write as well:

```
output.addPage(rhs)
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not get, you want album oriented pdf? By that I mean 2 pages on 1 paper. Or you want, like me, 2 pages separately. Because if you want album oriented pdf file, than the code, you showed me on github deals good.

Comment: @levgenii yes I want 2 pages side by side. My  code above is based  on that github  example.The problem I have is that the code works with SOME pdf files but it fails with other files

Comment: I see, do not know why either